Android view overlay not preventing clicking on controls behind it
Hey all I am trying to figure out what it is I am doing incorrectly since this does not seem to block my controls that are behind the view overlay.
This is my xml layout code:
<RelativeLayout>
   [all controls code here]
   <View
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="378dp"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="107dp"
      android:background="#86000000"
      android:elevation="2000dp" 
   />
</RelativeLayout>

and from the preview it is covering everything:

But when I go and run it - I am able to click on the controls in the background as if the overlay was not even there...
What would I be missing here in order for it to block those controls behind it?


Try android:clickable="true" on the <View>.

override the on touch listener for the overlay view and return true so that its not propagated down

@CommonsWare crazy enough that does work. Thanks! Please provide that as the answer so that I can give you credit.

By default, a View does not handle touch events. Whether by making it clickable via android:clickable="true", adding a TouchListener, or something, you need to teach the View to handle touch events.
